# How to pass pointer to function member when pointer to function is expected

Tags: c++, function, pointers, callback, member

I have tried using few solutions on this forum, but frankly speaking they are all confusing and I don't understand how I can apply them to my code. 
So I have:

```
class A { public: ... 
A(args..., void (*myCallback)())
};
```

It works for ordinary functions, but when I try this

```
class B { public: void member(){}};
B temp;
A myobj(args..., temp.member);
```

It doesn't work. As far as I know that's because pointers to member functions have hidden this parameter, so the arg list doesn't match. I can't make class A static for design reasons. And making additional constructor for each class I can possibly pass into it is my temporary solution, but I use constructor for literaly every class I have in my project. Is there any universal solution? I have read that std::bind or templates is the way to go, but I am not familiar with them. Especialy bind is very confusing, because of the poor resources to read about it, so I was thinking about something like

```
template<typename> var;
class A { ... 
    A(args..., void (*myCallback)(var))
    };
```

But ofc it is not how you use templates, because compiler gives me errors on that.

Comment: My advice is to stop using pointers to (member or non-member) functions, and instead use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Then you can *bind* any function (including member functions) using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or even use [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to help you. It will make life easier.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Would you mind specifing how using lambdas could help here?

Comment: Say you have a member function `Foo::someFunc()`, and an `std::function func`, you can do: `func = [this]() {someFunc();};` from within the class

Comment: ^^ 
lambda is the way to go

Comment: @Missqu Lambdas in combination with `std::function`.